# Formatting Numbers with Decimal

Tags: java, formatting

I'm trying to convert a number to currency with the codes below, but it is not what I exactly wanted.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

But it shows like this 
when I input six "3"

```
333,333.00
```

what I wanted is:

```
3,333.33
```

anyone have thoughts how to make this?

Comment: result is correct. decimal value is not present in given input.

Comment: Divide it by 100 not solved the problem

Comment: This is just plain wrong. How about when you actually receive 3333.33 as input. Do you really want to display it as 33.33? Since, your inputs have "," I guess you're dealing with currency and this is a bad way of doing things.

Comment: Solved it  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((value*.0100));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using this format

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((value*.0100));
```

thanks for all who post their idea

Answer (score 1):

try this parsed is input string
float parsed = 333333.0;

String formated = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

Comment: it still not showing. When I put 2 numbers it wont show, when I put 3 it shows like this  2.00

Comment: use float number if i use 333333.0 then output is 3,333.33

Comment: I vote you up for giving me an idea. I solved it using this            total =  ""+NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((value*.010));

Answer (score -1):

To control how many decimal places are shown use [NumberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29) and [NumberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits%28int%29).

Comment: Note that the number of places after the dot are the same in both instances. This isn't the problem or what they asked for.